# ArcPy approach to add lat/long to CSV for multiple sets in one row

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, csv, latitude-longitude

I have a CSV where each row contains 3 sets of coordinates in EPSG 32611 (UTM). I'd like to add columns that contain the coordinates in lat/long (EPSG 4326) also. So, columns H&I would be cols. B&C in lat/long; col. J&K would be cols. D&E in lat/long; and col. L&M would be F&G in lat/long:

[image]

Currently I've tried doing this by using MakeXYEventLayer for each of the three original UTM pairs (cols. B&C, D&E, F&G) and saving them into their own shapefile. I guess the next steps are to calculate geometry xy to add lat/long and then do a table join based on "PT_ID" 3x. This seems tedious and inefficient. Is there a more efficient and arc-pythonic tools I should do instead?

```
### STEP 2: import all points CSV generated by Matlab and cleanup
### STEP 3: make smaller, easier CSV tables for fault zone edge1 and edge2
### STEP 4: create points SHP for all points CSV
###         create temp points SHP for fault zone edge1 and edge2
### STEP 5: calcualte geometry x/y in lat/long for each of 3 pairs???
### STEP 6: table join based on PT_ID, join shpOut_edge1.shp to _allCenterPoints.shp
###         and then also table join, based on PT_ID, join shpOut_edge2.shp to _allCenterPoints_wEdge1.shp 

import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
inputFile = r'C:\Users\X\Documents\python\Dataset_allPoints.csv'
outpath = r'C:\Users\X\Documents\python\outputs'


############################################################
###     STEP 2
############################################################

import os
fileOut_allPts = outpath + '\\' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(inputFile))[0] + '_organized.csv'

import csv
with open(inputFile, 'r') as infile, open(fileOut_allPts, 'wb') as outfile:
    columnNames = ['PT_ID', 'PT_UTMx', 'Side1_X', 'Side1_Y', 'Side2_X', 'Side2_Y']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames = columnNames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        writer.writerow(row)

del infile, outfile, columnNames, writer, row


############################################################
###     STEP 3
############################################################

fileOut_edge1 = outpath + '\\' + 'temp_' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(inputFile))[0] + '_FaultZoneSide1.csv'

with open(inputFile, 'r') as infile, open(fileOut_edge1, 'wb') as outfile:
    columnNames = ['PT_ID', 'Side1_X', 'Side1_Y']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames = columnNames, extrasaction = 'ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        writer.writerow(row)

del infile, outfile, columnNames, writer, row


fileOut_edge2 = outpath + '\\' + 'temp_' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(inputFile))[0] + '_FaultZoneSide2.csv'

with open(inputFile, 'r') as infile, open(fileOut_edge2, 'wb') as outfile:
    columnNames = ['PT_ID', 'Side2_X', 'Side2_Y']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames = columnNames, extrasaction = 'ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        writer.writerow(row)

del infile, outfile, columnNames, writer, row


############################################################
###     STEP 4
############################################################

########## Set local variables
in_Table = fileOut_allPts
inputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(input_epsg)
x_coords = "PT_UTMx"
y_coords = "PT_UTMy"
z_coords = ""
out_layer = "pts_layer"
shpOut_allPts = '_allCenterPoints.shp'

# Execute MakeXYEventLayer
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(in_Table, x_coords, y_coords, out_layer, inputCoordinateSystem, z_coords)

# Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(out_layer, outpath, shpOut_allPts)

# Clean up
del in_Table, inputCoordinateSystem, x_coords, y_coords, z_coords, out_layer


########## Set local variables
in_Table = fileOut_edge1
inputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(input_epsg)
x_coords = "Side1_X"
y_coords = "Side1_Y"
z_coords = ""
out_layer = "outLayer"
shpOut_edge1 = 'temp_' + '_Edge1.shp'

# Execute MakeXYEventLayer
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(in_Table, x_coords, y_coords, out_layer, inputCoordinateSystem, z_coords)

# Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(out_layer, outpath, shpOut_edge1)

# Clean up
del in_Table, inputCoordinateSystem, x_coords, y_coords, z_coords, out_layer


########## Set local variables
in_Table = fileOut_edge2
inputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(input_epsg)
x_coords = "Side2_X"
y_coords = "Side2_Y"
z_coords = ""
out_layer = "outLayer"
shpOut_edge2 = 'temp_' + '_Edge2.shp'

# Execute MakeXYEventLayer
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(in_Table, x_coords, y_coords, out_layer, inputCoordinateSystem, z_coords)

# Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(out_layer, outpath, shpOut_edge2)

# Clean up
del in_Table, inputCoordinateSystem, x_coords, y_coords, z_coords, out_layer

############################################################
###     STEP 5 calculate geometry xy lat/long for each of 3 pairs??
############################################################

# ???


############################################################
###     STEP 6 multiple tabe joins???
############################################################

# multiple table joins??
```

Part of the table as text:

```
PT_ID,PT_UTMx,PT_UTMy,Side1_X,Side1_Y,Side2_X,Side2_Y
1,534738.03,3830471.97,534737.69,3830471.60,534756.47,3830491.69
2,534869.97,3830346.05,534869.63,3830345.68,534986.94,3830470.78
3,535007.99,3830214.05,535007.65,3830213.69,535071.71,3830281.79
4,535121.97,3830087.96,535121.55,3830087.69,535139.66,3830099.28
5,535206.00,3829955.98,535205.57,3829955.72,535229.06,3829970.02
```

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: Probably because you tagged your question arcpy without including code. I disagree with the blanket closing of coding language tagged questions with no code as sometimes no code is needed. For what it's worth, no there's no such tool. You'll need to write a script or build a model.

Comment: You and read and write the csv using csv module. Create a Point geometry for each Point and use projectas method to get coordinates in 4326, then write back to csv. You can also use pandas module instead of csv. What ArcGIS version do you have? Add a code attempt and your question will be reopened.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks Luke & Bera. It looks like I need to create a couple extra unnecessary point files first then. Thanks again

Comment: Code attempt added--looking forward to your ideas @BERA